# Inconsistent handling of a recipe for the "--just-print" command-line option

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

***From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Instead-of-Execution.html#Instead-of-Execution):***

> The `-n`, `-t`, and `-q` options do not affect recipe lines that
>   begin with `+` characters or contain the strings `$(MAKE)` or `${MAKE}`.
>   Note that only the line containing the `+` character or the strings
>   `$(MAKE)` or `${MAKE}` is run regardless of these options.  Other lines
>   in the same rule are not run unless they too begin with `+` or contain
>   `$(MAKE)` or `${MAKE}`.

***Now, given a makefile:***

```make
# 'test -f foo' is "false".
$(shell rm -rf foo)
# 'test -f bar' is "true".
$(shell rm -rf bar; touch bar)

# 'test -f bar' will be executed, even for -[tnq] command-line options. NOT SO, for 'test -f foo'.
define cmd
test -f 'foo'
+test -f 'bar'
endef


1 2 ::
    $(cmd)
```

***And running, we get:***

```console
$ make --just-print 1
test -f 'foo'
test -f 'bar'

#####################

$ make --just-print 2
test -f 'foo'
test -f 'bar'

#####################

$ make --just-print 1 2
test -f 'foo'
test -f 'bar'
test -f 'foo'
makefile:14: recipe for target '2' failed
make: *** [2] Error 1

#####################

$ make --just-print 2 1
test -f 'foo'
test -f 'bar'
test -f 'foo'
makefile:14: recipe for target '1' failed
make: *** [1] Error 1
```

Clearly, we have here 4 cases:

1. `make --just-print 1`

   - `test -f foo`, clearly a "false" command, **succeeds** here. This is, because of the `--just-print` command-line option, so Make did not really "run" it. It was a mere *echo*.
   - `test -f bar`, a command that was **actually** run, due to the `+` prefix. But given that this recipe is a "true" command, it is not a surprise that it succeeds.
2. `make --just-print 2`

   - **Exactly** as *case 1*. Well, the target, that the recipe was executed *for*, may be different here (`2` vs. `1`), but the recipe executed was 100% **identical**. This includes the "logic" behind their success, explained in `case 1`.
3. `make --just-print 1 2`

   - This is more complicated. It starts off as in `case 1`, and for the same reasons, both: `test -f foo` and `test -f bar` succeed.
   - But, When Make has to "repeat" the same "routine", by executing the recipe for `2`, a fatal error occurs. Why?
4. `make --just-print 2 1`

   - The same as `case 3`, but `2` and `1` targets play here sort of an "opposite" role. That is, execution for `2` succeeds (As per `case 2`) but then fails on target `1`.

Now, there is no doubt, that something is wrong here.

As Make is never supposed to fail for `test -f foo`, when executing in `--just-print` mode.

Simply, because Make is not allowed to execute the command. It should merely echo it!

So, what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It's something to do with the expansion of multiline variables with the contents containing `+` on one line but not the others.  If you write the rule using normal content instead of multiline variables, then it works in all cases:

```
1 2 ::
        test -f 'foo'
        +test -f 'bar'
```

You should file a bug about this special situation.  Variables containing multiple lines are tricky because they appear as only one line when first parsed by make but expand into multiple lines when executed.